# how to import filtered rows before reading csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have to upload large number of csv files in pandas dataframe. Can I filter out data from these csv files before loading it so as I dont get any memory error.

I the existing set up it gives me memory error

I have a column Location which has 32 values but I only want 3-4 locations to be filtered before importing.

Is this possible?

Comment: Check `usecols` , you can define which columns to import. check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) . Also if you want a large file to be imported, there is something called `chunks` which reads the values in chunks. All examples already exist in this platform :)

Comment: I am already using usecols for using limited columns but I need to filter out rows. I have around 50M rows out of which I need to filter to work upon

Comment: For that you can process in chunks. something like `chunksize = 5000
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)` and then do your manipulation

Comment: How often do you need to do this? Every day? Just once? If the answer is more than once maybe you should consider exporting your data to a database and use SQL-language to load the frames.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read line by line and keep only the records you need:

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

After that you can save your filtered rows to csv files using [writerow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)